# Keras custom layer(with another custom layer as super class) not accepting multiple inputs

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

I am trying to implement a Keras custom layer whose super class is another custom layer. The super class take one input and it's working fine. But the sub class which is supposed to take two inputs isn't accepting multiple inputs.

I have tried to pair the super class with Layer. But it was the same. I think there's some problem in building step.

```py
class SpadeLayer(ConvSN2D, Layer):

    def __init__(self, filters, kernel_size, **kwargs):
        super(SpadeLayer, self).__init__(filters, kernel_size, **kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.bn = BatchNormalization(center=False, scale=False)
        self.conv0 = ConvSN2D(128, kernel_size , strides=1, padding='same',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform')
        self.conv1 = ConvSN2D(filters, kernel_size , strides=1, padding='same',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform')
        self.conv2 = ConvSN2D(filters, kernel_size , strides=1, padding='same',kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform')
        super(SpadeLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs):
        _, f_h, f_w, _ = inputs[0].get_shape().as_list()
        segmap_down = K.tf.image.resize_images(inputs[1], (f_h, f_w))

        init_conv = self.conv0()(segmap_down)
        gamma = self.conv1()(init_conv)
        beta = self.conv1()(init_conv)
        return (self.bn(features) * gamma) + beta

layer = SpadeLayer(3, 3)
input1 = Input(shape=(16,16,32))
input2 = Input(shape=(16,16,1))
output = layer([input1, input2])
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input], outputs=[output])
model.summary()
```

I am getting following error:

```py
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-45f88bca3df3> in <module>
      2 input1 = Input(shape=(16,16,32))
      3 input2 = Input(shape=(16,16,1))
----> 4 output = layer([input1, input2])
      5 model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[input], outputs=[output])
      6 model.summary()

C:\Anaconda3\envs\env_tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
    412                 # Raise exceptions in case the input is not compatible
    413                 # with the input_spec specified in the layer constructor.
--> 414                 self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
    415 
    416                 # Collect input shapes to build layer.

C:\Anaconda3\envs\env_tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py in assert_input_compatibility(self, inputs)
    297                              'but it received ' + str(len(inputs)) +
    298                              ' input tensors. Input received: ' +
--> 299                              str(inputs))
    300         for input_index, (x, spec) in enumerate(zip(inputs, input_spec)):
    301             if spec is None:

ValueError: Layer spade_layer_11 expects 1 inputs, but it received 2 input tensors. Input received: [<tf.Tensor 'input_21:0' shape=(?, 16, 16, 32) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'input_22:0' shape=(?, 16, 16, 1) dtype=float32>]
```

I just don't know what I can do to rectify it. I have check many resources, but haven't found anything similar.

Comment: Maybe you want to concatenate the inputs or something similar?

Comment: Your `spadelayer` accepts two inputs (i.e. `input_1` and `input_2`). But you are setting up a model which uses a single input (`input`). If you want the `SpadeLayer` to work properly you should have a model which accepts two inputs `input_1` and `input_2`.